# How can i get average of count in multiple tables in MySql?

Tags: mysql

The **_helper_calendar** table is simple a helper table to fill date gaps with no results. So i get every date between start and end date.

I have added explaination to each line of code so that its clear what i am trying to achieve. **I am actually get back the error saying: "invalide use of group function..."**

Here is my query:

```
   SELECT 
    /*get the day date*/
    cal.datefield AS cal_date, 
    /*get appointments by date from user*/
    (SELECT COUNT(e1.id) FROM events_table e1 WHERE DATE(e1.start) = DATE(cal.datefield) AND e1.user_id = 1 ) AS appointments, 
     /*get sales by date from user*/
    (SELECT COUNT(s1.id) FROM sales_table s1 WHERE DATE(s1.created) = DATE(cal.datefield) AND s1.user_id  = 1) AS sales,
       /*get average appointments by date from all users*/
    (SELECT COUNT(e2.id) FROM events_table e2 WHERE DATE(e2.start) = DATE(cal.datefield) ) AS appointments_avg, 
      /*get average sales by date from all users*/
    (SELECT AVG(COUNT(s2.id)) FROM sales_table s2 WHERE DATE(s2.created) = DATE(cal.datefield)) AS sales_avg
FROM events_table e 
    RIGHT JOIN _helper_calendar AS cal ON (DATE(e.start) = cal.datefield)
WHERE DATE(cal.datefield) BETWEEN '2018-06-01' AND '2018-07-31' 
GROUP BY cal_date
```

Here is a shorter query which produces the same error. Of course i need it to work in the same context like above, but maybe this helps for better understanding?

```
SELECT s.start, AVG(COUNT(s.id)) s2_cnt FROM sales_table s WHERE DATE(s.start) BETWEEN '2018-06-01' AND '2018-07-31'  GROUP BY DATE(s.start);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your query using left joins from your calendar table to the other tables and using aggregate functions grouping by the date:

```
SELECT
    cal.datefield AS cal_date,
    COUNT(e1.id) AS appointments, 
    COUNT(s1.id) AS sales
FROM _helper_calendar AS cal
LEFT JOIN events_table e ON DATE(e.start) = cal.datefield
LEFT JOIN events_table e1 ON DATE(e1.start) = DATE(cal.datefield)
   AND e1.user_id = 1
LEFT JOIN salestable ON DATE(s1.created) = DATE(cal.datefield)
   AND s1.user_id = 1
WHERE DATE(cal.datefield) BETWEEN '2018-06-01' AND '2018-07-31'
GROUP BY cal.datefield
```

and join this query to another query that gets the average for all users for each date joining on date.

Comment: can you give an example how to rewrite with left joins? i just removed the group By portion of code and error remains same...?

Comment: @jhondano see updated answer. I also corrected an error in your query where you were using `COUNT` instead of `AVG` for `appointments_avg`

Comment: AVG(e2.id) will not return average of count, but i think average of ids!?

Comment: @jhondano looking at your query more closely you want the average across *all* users in each user's data, so you need to join 2 subqueries on date - one subquery for the user and one for all users. I'm not going to do it as it's a bit of work and beyond the normal fair scope of an answer

Comment: ok can you get this to work?: 
SELECT s.start, AVG(COUNT(s.id)) s2_cnt FROM sales_table s WHERE DATE(s.start) BETWEEN '2018-06-01' AND '2018-07-31'  GROUP BY DATE(s.start); basically its the same thing but since it has the issue i am wondering how is the best to do it?

Comment: you have to take the average of the results of a subquery that counts